# jQuery override form submit not working when submit called by javascript on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a page with a normal form with a submit button and some jQuery which binds to the form submit event and overrides it with `e.preventDefault()` and runs an AJAX command. This works fine when the submit button is clicked but when a link with `onclick='document.formName.submit();'` is clicked, the event is not caught by the AJAX form submit event handler. Any ideas why not or how to get this working without binding to all the a elements?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- Overwrite the submit function to do your evil bidding

```
    var oldSubmit = form.submit;
    form.submit = function() {
        $(form).trigger("submit");
        oldSubmit.call(form, arguments);
    }
```

- Why not bind to all the <a> tags?  Then you don't have to do any monkey patching, and it could be as simple as (assuming all the links are inside the form tag):

```
    $("form a").click(function() {
        $(this).parents().filter("form").trigger("submit");
    });
```

Comment: What does 'form' stand for in the first example?

Comment: @tishma The form DOM element, like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/931482/1048862

Comment: This will not work in some older browsers. JS .submit property is the reason. Use $().submit(function() {...}); instead.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using jQuery, you should be attaching events via it's own [event mechanism](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) and not by using "on" properties (onclick etc.). It also has its own event triggering method, aptly named '[trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#typedata)', which you should use to activate the form submission event.

Comment: I concur - don't use obtrusive JavaScript in your code, it just makes for headaches if you are mingling unobtrusive JavaScript with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Eran

I am using this event binding code

```
this._form.bind('submit', Delegate.create(this, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this._searchFadeOut();
    this.__onFormSubmit.invoke(this, new ZD.Core.GenericEventArgs(this._dateField.attr('value')));
});
```

but there is legacy `onclick` code on the HTML and I would prefer not to change it as there are just so many links.

Comment: The problem is that calling the form's submit() method will not activate the event. It's the same with an input focus() method - they simply do not go through the regular event delegation chain.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Make a dummy button, hide the real submit with the name submit,

and then:

```
$("#mySubmit").click(function(){
    $("#submit").trigger("click"); });
```

set an event handler on your dummy to trigger click on the form submit button. let the browser figure out how to submit the form... This way you don't need to `preventDefault` on the form submit which is where the trouble starts.

This seemed to work around the problem.