# Does jQuery handle events without setting the normal event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a div on an HTML page, I used jQuery to add a click event handler:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){    

      $("div").click(function() { alert("clicked!"); });

  });
```

Then I used the Visual Studio 2008 (or IE8) debugger to step through the javascript/jquery. I expected to see a value in the debugger for:

```
$(“div”)[0].onclick
```

(`$(“div”)[0]` being the first div in the collection of results of the selector, `$(“div”)`).

But I don’t. I thought jQuery’s event assignment methods (e.g., .click(function)) were actually assigning values to an element’s underlying events. They’re not?

In other words, these two lines of code don’t have the same affect, but I thought they would:

```
$("div").click(function() { alert("clicked!"); }); // (Line 1)
$("div")[0].onclick = function() { alert("clicked!"); }; // (Line 2)
```

Can anyone explain this or point out if I’m doing something wrong? I would like to use line 1 in my code, but for my needs it seems I’ll have to use line 2 (FYI, I am planning to use an actual function, and not just show alerts :-) ).

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you care if it's the `onclick` attribute that gets set or not... Can you clarify?

Comment: Sure. I want to verify that what I'm seeing is correct, and understand it. The fact is I'm dealing with the same problem as described in these posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142000/jquery-override-form-submit-not-working-when-submit-called-by-javascript-on-a-ele

But I'm not asking for a solution to that issue.

In short, programmatically calling submit() on a form does not cause the onsubmit event handlers to fire.  (continued…).

Comment: Therefore, when the ASP .NET rendered javascript method, __doPostBack is called, it checks for "onsubmit" event handlers, and runs them, with this line:

if (theForm.onsubmit == null || theForm.onsubmit())

It therby avoids the problem that's decribed in the two links I posted above, in the case of wanting to run an event handler whenever __doPostBack is called. Which in my opinion, is fantastic.


It then calls "theForm.submit()".

So, I need onsubmit to be set, and I can do that with my "line 2" in the question I posted, but not with "line 1."

Comment: This explained the if(theForm.onsubmitt == null... line of code.
http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2004/03/01/NoMoreHijackingOfDoPostBackInWhidbey.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not use the onclick attribute to attach events to elements. It uses either attachEvent(IE) or addEventListener(all others).  You can find the smoking gun in lines 2500-2502 of the uncompressed [jquery-1.3.2.js](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js).

You should be able to, however, place a breakpoint inside your jQuery event handler and have Visual Studio stop there.  Either click inside the body of the event handler (e.g. on "alert") before hitting F9, or break the event handler body into a its own line, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("div").click(function() {
        alert("clicked!"); // place a breakpoint on this line
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The difference between attachEvent()/addEventListener() and the onclick/onsubmit attribute is what I needed to know. 

I've also downloaded the "dev" version of jQuery and looked at those lines of code, 2500-2502. I've done some experimenting and come to a better understanding.

Now I'm just not sure why we even have the onclick attribute, in addition to, and completely separate of, a set of event handlers. If onclick represented the list of handlers, and we could use: onclick += function(), and/or attachEvent(), that might explain it to me, but that's not it.

Comment: onclick is indeed inconsistent with- and less powerful than attachEvent and addEventListener. It is there for historical reasons -- it was there first. The methods were added later, as DOM developers were coming to grips with the needs to separate code from markup and for multiple handlers per element/event.