# Create a handler for myform.submit() which works from a button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, cross-browser, jquery-events

For some reason the submit event is different in these 2 cases.  Please help understand why.  Here is a form with a submit and a button.  Click submit and alert fires, click button and the  alert doesn't fire.  What's different about the form element?  How do I make both work the same?  BTW: I am testing in Chrome. This needs to work for all browsers that support  `myform.submit();`.

```
<FORM id="myform" action="saveform.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="my_val" value="" />
<INPUT id="button" value="Save Button" class="save-submit" type=button >
<INPUT id="button" value="Save Submit" class="save-submit-hidden" type=submit>
</FORM>
<script language=javascript>


        $("form").submit(function() {
            alert('submitting');
            return false;
        });


    $('.save-submit').click(function() {
        myform.submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For one, you have a number of issues with your HTML. All form elements should have a name, and you should not have 2 elements with the same ID on a page.

Comment: Also, all your attributes should be quoted.  `type="button"` and `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myform.submit();
```

should be

```
$(myform).submit();
```

and with that it works for me.

EDIT:

This seems to be a misfeature in jQuery: [jQuery override form submit not working when submit called by javascript on a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142000/jquery-override-form-submit-not-working-when-submit-called-by-javascript-on-a-ele)

Comment: that works for me too, however I am trying to understand why it doesn't catch the other event.

Comment: Without the `$`, you're calling javascript's submit function, not jQuery's. It could be a bug/misfeature in jQuery, but it looks like when you submit that way, it bypasses the normal submit event. But when you actually click a submit button (or use jQuery to submit the form) then jQuery receives the event normally and calls your other handler properly.

Comment: Yeah, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142000/jquery-override-form-submit-not-working-when-submit-called-by-javascript-on-a-ele. Can't find a jQuery bug report for it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#myform').submit();`?

Comment: @Rocket: That's what I had at first. I thought `myform` would be an undefined variable, but apparently every `id` in HTML automatically creates a JS variable? Anyway, I thought I would make the smallest change possible so the difference jumps out at you.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all of the javascript.  Clicking an input of type=submit on a form causes it to submit, no javascript required.  Unless you need some javascript to run every time the form is submitted (and no matter HOW it is submitted), in that case use your $("form").submit function and delete the $('.save-submit').click function.