# Form submit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have written a function on submit of a form like this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    // do something
});
```

And form is submitted like this:

```
document.formName.submit();
```

It doesn't trigger my function. If I wrap form in jQuery and then submit it, it works fine:

```
$(document.formName).submit();
```

I was thinking binding events to jQuery DOM object will trigger the events on raw DOM object as well, but it doesn't happen in this case.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aZasZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.formName.submit();
```

does not trigger the event as it is the actual DOM Element and does not fire off any events,

while

```
$(document.formName).submit();
```

is a trigger function for firing of events within JQuery.

i would suggest you use the

```
$('form').submit();
```

to submit the form or

```
$('form').triggerHandler('submit')
```

in the case of you wanting to fire only that function handler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("form#myForm").submit();
```

and this is the whole code:

```
    <form id="MyForm" method="POST" action="">
        Field1:<input type="text" id="field1" value="" />
        Field2:<input type="text" id="field2" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>

    <button id="ShowLink">Vai</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form#MyForm").submit( function () {
              alert("Hello!");
              return(true);
            } );
        })
    </script>
```

UPDATE:

To achieve what you're trying to do you can overwrite the submit function. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/4HVZY/).
Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/142109/219406).

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have gotten your IDs wrong.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the behavior, feel free to use that.

http://jsfiddle.net/aZasZ/

(I just added $("#form").submit() )

Comment: you didn't understand me. I am submitting form using document.formName. It doesn't work. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/aZasZ/1/

Comment: @emphaticsunshine: read Qpirate's answer. He's telling you why!

Comment: @emphaticsunshine: have a look at my updated answer. Maybe it can help.